# sql type conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I have a column datedocumented in the format YYYYMMDD and of the datatype nvarchar. I want to change the data type to datetime and update the column name exdatedocumented and alter the table using ALTER .can anyone help in this.I have tried something like this

```
update dbo.table2
set [DateDocumented] = convert(datetime,CAST([DateDocumented] as datetime),130)
```

I ended up getting error

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated
```

.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific functionality used there...)

Comment: I am using sql server management studio 2014

Comment: You're converting the value to `datetime` *twice*, the first time with no attempt to control how it's interpreted. And in the second, where did you pull [130 from](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just change the column type:

```
alter dbo.table2 alter column DateDocumented datetime;
```

Your column is in a format suitable for conversion.  If you wanted to use default formats instead, just do:

```
update table dbo.table2
    set [DateDocumented] = convert(datetime, CAST([DateDocumented] as datetime));
```

This should also allow the column to be converted to a `datetime`.

Comment: Msg 343, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Unknown object type 'dbo' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER statement.
This is the i got after trying above code

Comment: Gordon missed the word TABLE after the ALTER work. So the command should be something like: ALTER TABLE dbo.table2 ALTER COLUMN  DateDocumented datetime;

Answer (score 0):

1st change that column name then alter table

```
sp_RENAME 'dbo.table2.datedocumented', 'exdatedocumented' , 'COLUMN'
go
ALTER TABLE dbo.table2
ALTER COLUMN exdatedocumented datetime;
```

Comment: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.This is the error i am getting

Comment: @cherry what type of values are right now in your exiting column

Comment: data type of datedocumented column is nvarchar

Comment: data type of datedocumented column is nvarchar

Comment: @cherry CREATE  table table2 (datedocumented NVARCHAR(500));

GO
 sp_RENAME 'dbo.table2.datedocumented', 'exdatedocumented' , 'COLUMN'
go
ALTER TABLE dbo.table2
ALTER COLUMN exdatedocumented datetime;

Comment: i just created in local and check it work i think you have some data that not formatted to date that why this error thrown

Answer (score 0):

It seems we have two things going on here. Changing the type for a column. And changing the name for a column. Let's try to keep these separate so not to confuse things. I will adress the changing of type (from varchar to datetime):

First of all: Why datetime? Why note datetime2 (with whatever fractions of seconds you want, for instance datetime2(0))? The new types for date and time has been around for 10 years now!

Anyhow, you apparently have values in your table which are not valid dates! First thing you need to do is to find those rows and handle them. Lets say that you will change to datetime2(0), if not, then just change below to datetime instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Table2
WHERE TRY_CAST(DateDocumented AS datetime2(0)) IS NULL
```